# How 'yield' works inside a block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm having hard time understanding the code below

```
  module MyEnumerable
      def my_select
        new_array = []
        each do |value|
          new_array << value if yield(value)
        end
        new_array
      end
    end
    
    class Week
      include MyEnumerable
    
      def initialize
        @days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"]
      end
      def each
        @days.each { |day| yield day }
      end
    end
    
    week = Week.new
    puts week.my_select { |day| day.start_with?("T") }
```

The Programme results the output

```
Tuesday
Thrusday
```

The ambiguous code

```
def each
   @days.each { |day| yield day }
end
```

1.There is no block given to 'yield', but code still works.

2.Isn't 'yield' to be used inside a method to which a block is given? It is clear that 'yield' inside a method invokes a block.

3.How does 'yield' inside a block works ?

---

refactored 'my_select' method as

```
    def my_select
        new_array = []
        each { |value| new_array << value if yield(value) }
        new_array
      end
    end
```

'each' method yields the block

```
 each { |value| new_array << value if yield(value) }  
 def each
   @days.each { |day| yield day }
 end
```

'my_select' method yields the block

```
week.my_select { |day| day.start_with?("T") }
def my_select
  new_array = []
  each { |value| new_array << value if yield(value) }
  new_array
end
```

Comment: 1. `yield` doesn't need to be given a block. It uses the block from the current scope. If you try to `yield`, but this method call does not have a block, you get an exception ("no block given") 2. Yes, both `yields` in your code are in methods that are passed blocks. 3. Exactly the same way it works outside of that block.

Comment: What do you mean there is no block given? `each { |value| new_array << value if yield(value)}`. Your `each` method yields `day` which you are accepting as `value` and then you are yielding value to the block sent to `my_select` (`{ |day| day.start_with?("T") }`), which you are accepting as `day`. In all cases yield has a block to yield to

Comment: @current_user as an aside a standard idiom for a deferred each would generally look like `def each(&block); @days.each(&block); end`. Basically it just passes the block on which is semi equivalent to your current implementation other than if no block is passed it will return an each Enumerator for the instance variable `@days`

Answer (score 0):

> The ambiguous code
>
> ```rb
> def each
>   @days.each { |day| yield day }
> end
> ```
>
> 1.There is no block given to 'yield', but code still works.

You don't pass a block directly to `yield`. You pass a block when calling the enclosing method and `yield` will invoke that block, e.g.:

```
week = Week.new
week.each { |day| puts day }
#             │ 
#             └──── from `yield day'
```

> 2.Isn't 'yield' to be used inside a method to which a block is given? It is clear that 'yield' inside a method invokes a block.

Yes, exactly. The invocation in your code is a little indirect. You are including `MyEnumerable` and its `my_select` method then calls your `each` method:

```
# ┌─────────────── this is your `each' method
# │
each do |value|
  new_array << value if yield(value)
end
```

The `do |value| ... end` is the block you were looking for. (`my_select` also yields `value` to its own block, hence the other `yield`)

> 3.How does 'yield' inside a block works ?

There's nothing special about it. `@days.each { |day| yield day }` calls `yield` for each element in `@days`. If we assume a static array content, your `each` method could be rewritten as:

```
def each
  yield "Monday"
  yield "Tuesday"
  yield "Wednesday"
  yield "Thursday"
  yield "Friday"
end
```